# Is there a way for the typescript compiler to throw an error when using the "any" type explicitly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rules, typechecking, explicit

I am trying to make my code as strict as possible with TS. Is there a way to make the following declaration using "any" as a type to throw an error since it should be a "string" type?

```js
const foo: any = "bar"
```

Comment: No. I'm hoping for the compiler to actually throw an error and have the build fail if "any" is used.

Comment: `tsc` itself does not have this ability, but both ESLint and TSLint have rules to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a tslint/eslint rule to prevent it. Found some documentation here https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way for the compiler to throw an error but this is the next best thing. Thank you!